# Search for multiple words in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I couldn't find the answer I was looking for at this challenge. 
I'm using express in my back end and I'm trying to build a route to filter the results based on user input.
Here's what I have so far:

```
router.get(
  "/search",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const keyword = req.query.keyword;
    const location = req.query.location;
    if (keyword) {
      Task.paginate({
        limit: 10,
        sort: "_id"
      }).then(tasks => {
        let filtered = tasks.results.filter(task => {
          return task.title.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase());
        });
        res.json({ ...tasks, results: filtered });
      });
    } else if (location) {
      Task.paginate({
        limit: 10,
        sort: "_id"
      }).then(tasks => {
        let filtered = tasks.results.filter(task => {
          return task.location.toLowerCase().includes(location.toLowerCase());
        });
        res.json({ ...tasks, results: filtered });
      });
    }
  }
);
```

As you can see from this route, I'm sending user input via query strings. (keyword and location). If the user passed only the keyword, I filter the tasks to see if the title includes the string passed by the user.
This works fine in a scenario where the user searches for only one string.

```
Example:
Title: "Work to be done today"
Search input: work
output: tasks

Now, what about this scenario:
Title: "Work to be done today"
Search: work today
output: []
```

If I input two words that are not one after the other the task is not found. How can I search the entire string for the words from the input and return the task if any of the words are present? (regex?)

Comment: How the output is tasks in the first case?

Comment: Just iterate over words and apply `.filter` for each word.

Answer (score 3):

You could split your words and then for each of them, test if the word is present in the string, the first time a word is present in the string, you return true.

If you want to use a regex, this should work too (don't forget to escape javascript regex tokens like * ( ) etc):

```
var regex = new RegExp(words.split(" ").join('|'));
```

And then you can test the regex against the string

Comment: I don't know why people have dv this post.

Comment: Yes there is 1 dv and 2 uv on the post :(

Comment: Not my downvote, but actually, there is a problem with this approach: what if a "word" contains a `+`, or `(`, or `)`? It won't work then.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape regex special tokens, but even though he can steel use the first approach..

Answer (score 2):

This search and return true is any of the words in search are in myString.

```js
const search = 'a aa aaa';
const myString = 'are a aa aaa';

console.log(search.split(' ').some(item => myString.includes(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Match any word from the multiple words searches.

```js
const isMatchAnyWords = (search, content) => {

  // Lowarize the search term and the content.
  search = search.toLocaleLowerCase();
  content = content.toLocaleLowerCase();

  // Remove all inner spaces and keep only one space between two words.
  search = search.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim()

  // Add the pipe operator to match any single world.
  search = search.replace(' ', '|');

  // Match any word in the content.
  if (content.match(new RegExp(search, "g"))) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

/** Usage */

let content = 'My name is Mahesh Waghmare with 7 years of experience.'

// Check exact string exists.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords('Mahesh', content) ); // true, 

// Match without case sensetive.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords(' mahesh', content) ); // true, 

// Match Mixed cases.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords(' WaGhMare Mahesh', content) ); // true

// Match any single word.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords(' Waghmare  Not  Mahesh', content) ); // true

// Not match.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords('Rajesh', content) ); // false

// Match at least one word.
console.log( isMatchAnyWords(' Waghmare Rajesh', content) ); // true
```